# How to show a NavigationBar on detailViewController of SplitViewController iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

i am using the new iOS 8 SplitViewController i am setting only one detailViewController from storyboard and then i use `showDetailViewController()` to show a new viewController

```
self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(TableViewController(), sender: nil)
```

but the NavigationBar is always hidden is there a way to put a NavigationBar on the detailViewController

and yeah btw i tried to unhide the NavigationBar but not working

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply we can put a UINavigationController before `TableViewController` like this and show the navigationController

```
var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:TableViewController())
self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(nav, sender: nil)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it's working fine in iOS 13 .. Xcode 11

Answer (score 0):

I write this in prepareForSegue method of master. You will need to replace DetailViewController with TableViewController in your code. May be you can also write similar code in TableViewController's viewDidLoad as well, but I am not sure. For my code sample with this code, check this [Blog Post](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views/)

```
let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as DetailViewController

            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```